# How to convert mysql function into sqlsrv?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

```
$query = sqlsrv_query("select * from sessions where password='$password' AND username='$username'");
$rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; 
    header("location: profile.php"); 
} else {
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
```

Hi, I have this code but it's written in mysql and I want it to work in sqlserver so I changed `mysql_query` into `sqlsrv_query` and it didn't work properly, and I changed `mysql_num_rows` into `sqlsrv_num_rows` and it didn't work either so can anyone help me and tell me how to write them please?

Comment: What is `mysql_num_rows`. I guess there is nothing to do with the Sql query. It should work fine

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or free conversion service**

Comment: @VR46 sqlsrv_query() expects at least 2 parameters, it gives me this error for the sqlsrv_query

Comment: @VR46 and the sqlsrv_num_rows retrieves the number of rows in a result set

Comment: Please share the sqlsrv code you've tried.

Comment: You need to tell what `mysql_num_rows` is doing

Comment: @Mureinik $query = sqlsrv_query("select * from sessions where password='$password' AND 

username='$username'");
$rows = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username; 
header("location: profile.php"); 
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}

Comment: @VR46 i know but i can't get the syntax right

Comment: @stephjhonny it's impossible to read code posted in the comments. Could you please [edit] your question and include this code (properly formatted, of course)? Thanks!

Comment: @Mureinik done editing

Comment: @Mureinik Thank you so much! it worked perfectly :D but now i have to fix the num_rows bug :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the connection parameter to [`sqlsrv_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php). While you're at it, you might as well use bind variables instead of string substitution to help guard against SQL-Injection attacks.

```
$serverName = "serverName\instancename";
$connectionInfo = 
    array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$params = array($username, $password);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query
            ($conn, 
            'select * from sessions where password=? AND  username=?', 
            $params);
```